# jqGrid change collapce icon

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

We are using jqGrid version 4.6

We want to change the collapse icon. So below code does this job

```
$(".ui-icon-circlesmall-plus")
          .removeClass("ui-icon-circlesmall-plus")
          .addClass("ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s");
```

Where should I put this code?

I have put it in `gridComplete` like

```
gridComplete: function(){

      $(".ui-icon-circlesmall-plus")
          .removeClass("ui-icon-circlesmall-plus")
          .addClass("ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s");

}
```

but not working, how ever by adding a time out the code works fine:

```
gridComplete: function(){
              setTimeout( function(){
              (".ui-icon-circlesmall-plus")
                .removeClass("ui-icon-circlesmall-plus")
                .addClass("ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s");}, 1000);
        },
```

Sample At https://jsfiddle.net/jbb9173b/, If you remove the timeout the icon will not change !

Why do I need time out?! I am triggering bad event ? I mean is there another event which could eliminate the need of timeout function ?

Is there a better way?

Comment: You should always write which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fok of jqGrid. I can't help you with Guriddo jqGrid JS. Free  jqGrid supports Bootstrap too (see [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap) for example) with Bootstrap (glyph) or Font Awesome icons. One can easy customize any icon, but you should clear specify what you need. There are no common "collapse icon". Do you use TreeGrid, Subgrid or data grouping?

Comment: Dear Oleg, I have update my answer with also a jsfiddle ( Thanks for bootstrap link :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use `minusicon` and `plusicon` properties of `groupingView` to specify the icons used for data grouping. For example

```
groupingView: {
    minusicon: "ui-icon-arrowstop-1-n", // "ui-icon-circlesmall-minus"
    plusicon: "ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s",  // "ui-icon-circlesmall-plus"
    groupField: ["ProductName"],
    groupCollapse: true
}
```

with the results like on the picture below

[image]

see the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jbb9173b/2/

I still recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork instead of old jqGrid 4.6, which is already dead. It has absolutely new full customization icon system (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8)), where the icons could be not only jQuery UI icons, but Bootstrap's glyph icons, Font Awesome icons or any other. All default settings can be seen [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.4/js/grid.base.js#L370-L580). One can use `iconSet` option (for example `iconSet: "fontAwesome"`, `iconSet: "glyph"` or default iconSet: "jQueryUI") to specify the icon set, which one prefer to use. You should just include the corresponding CSS with the icons (`font-awesome.min.css` or `bootstrap.min.css`). One can easy change **any** icon from existing icon set and define in the way new custom set. For example, one can define

```
$.jgrid.icons.customjQueryUI = {
    baseIconSet: "jQueryUI",
    grouping: {
        plus: "ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s", //"ui-icon-circlesmall-plus"
        minus: "ui-icon-arrowstop-1-n" //"ui-icon-circlesmall-minus"
    }
};
```

and to use `iconSet: "customjQueryUI"` option. See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jbb9173b/3/, which uses jqGrid 4.13.4.

One can uses only Bootstrap's glyph icons:

```
$.jgrid.icons.customGlyph = {
    baseIconSet: "glyph",
    grouping: {
        plus: "glyphicon-save", //"glyphicon-expand"
        minus: "glyphicon-open" //"glyphicon-collapse-down"
    }
};
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/jbb9173b/5/, which displays

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It is a new project and I just switched to https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid